# Java: Round an Integer to an element of a given List

Tags: java, list, rounding

Supose i have a List of Integers: `ints = {0,10,20,30,40,50}` and an input value input = 17

How do i get the closest integer of the list to the given input? For my example it would be 20.

Or to restate the question: how do i round the input to the closest value of the list?

I couldn't find a function in Java that does something like that

Comment: What have you tried?-

Comment: what about to check the minimum difference as absolute value  between `input` and `ints[0,n-1]`

Comment: Not sure if such a function exists, but then: it is very easy to implement. If the list is sorted, you can use binary search to get to the "closest" entry for example. You see, right now it sounds like you simply want us to do your homework for you ... which isnt going to happen.

Comment: (you see, you dont need rounding here. the brute force solution is to just iterate your solution and stop when you hit the first number that is >= your input).

Comment: @GhostCat It's not a homework, but binary search sounds like the right way to go, thank you

Comment: Hi, @Felix00.  I suspect the downvotes your question has received are in part due to a lack of any indication what what's been attempted thus far.  For a better reception and a better chance of a helpful response, I would recommend updating your question with that information.

Comment: Question for the close voters due to lack of focus: how is this unfocused?  Both questions are equivalent ("how do I get the closest integer; how do I round to the closest value"), so while it appears there are two questions, it's really the same question restated.

Comment: @M.Justin People use that close reason for the lack of "zero evidence of own efforts included".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Java to do this exactly, as it's not something that's particularly useful in general.

One approach would be to notice that you are looking for the smallest deviation from `input`, that is to say, the value where `abs(number - input)` is closest to 0.

Using this knowledge, we can create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) that compares numbers based on their distance from the input, and pick the smallest number based on this comparator:

```java
List<Integer> ints = List.of(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
int input = 17;

Comparator<Integer> distanceFromInputComparator = 
        Comparator.comparing(value -> Math.abs(value - input));

System.out.println(ints.stream().min(distanceFromInputComparator).orElseThrow());
```

This returns 20, as requested.

There are some caveats with this implementation that could be addressed if necessary.  It currently throws an exception if the input list is empty.  It also picks arbitrarily if there are two closest (e.g. if 14 & 20 are in the list and the input is 17, it's not specified which would be picked by [`Stream.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min(java.util.Comparator))) since they're both "equal" according to the comparator.

To address the tiebreaker, you could add a secondary comparison if they're equidistant.  For instance, you could do either of the following:

```java
// Pick the smaller when there's a tie
Comparator<Integer> distanceFromInputComparator = Comparator
        .comparing((Integer value) -> Math.abs(value - input))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

// Pick the larger when there's a tie
Comparator<Integer> distanceFromInputComparator = Comparator
        .comparing((Integer value) -> Math.abs(value - input))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: @Felix00 After you are done writing the code , check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Eritrean Wouldn't that pick 20 over 16, even though 16 is closer to 17? It also assumes the input is sorted, which is not a stated precondition, either.

Comment: @M.Justin My mistake. I misunderstood the requierments.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm:

- Iterate through the list.
- For each element, compare the element with the input value.
- If the input value is *greater* than the current element, iterate to the next element.
- If the input value is greater than *all* elements, return some sentry value (MAX_VALUE) or something.
- If the input value is *lesser* than a given element, then it's rounded sufficiently and you would return that element.

There are ways to account for rounding *down*; you'll just have to reverse the direction of the inequality.  Half-rounding is left as an exercise for the reader.